# NodeJs: when start putting Arabic in JSON get converted to entities

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, utf-8, cheerio

I'm building an API from scraping a website, the website is an Arabic one and old.

I was first facing a problem that when I make a request to the website Html the server returns all the Arabic text in some weird symbols!!

**And I had solved this by using a lib called `iconv-lite` by this snippet  of code**

```js
// decoding the response to support arabic
responseBody = iconv.decode(Buffer.from(responseBody), "win1256");
```

Now, if I return the Html works great, but when I start to parse the HTML to extract data from it and return it into JSON format the issue gets back, the Arabic is shown as HTML entities.

**The response is something like this:!!! ( the text in each field of the JSON only Arabics one )**

```
"&#xA0;&#xA0;&#xA0;&#xA0;&#xA0;&#xA0;&#xA0;&#xA0;&#xA0;&#xA0;&#xA0;&#xA0;&#xA0;&#xA0;&#xA0;&#xA0;&#xA0;&#xA0;&#xA0;&#xA0;&#xA0;&#xA0;&#xA0;&#xA0;&#xA0; &#xA0;&#x628;&#x64A;&#x627;&#x646;&#x627;&#x62A; &#x627;&#x644;&#x637;&#x627;&#x644;&#x628; &#x627;&#x644;&#x623;&#x633;&#x627;&#x633;&#x64A;&#x629; &#xA0;&#xA0;&#xA0;&#xA0;&#xA0;&#xA0;&#xA0;&#xA0;&#xA0;&#xA0; ( &#x62F;&#x648;&#x631; &#x645;&#x627;&#x64A;&#x648; )"
```

Also if I **Stringify** the array the issue gets solved for some reason! **now I need to fix this as I need the data to be in JSON format**

**All code**

```js
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { load } from 'cheerio';
import { get } from 'request-promise';
import * as iconv from 'iconv-lite';



@Injectable()
export class FacultyService {
    async getStudentResultsBody(faculty: string = 'Ektsad', seatNumer: string = '240') {
        // search by seatnumber
        let responseBody = await get(`http://xxxx/xxxx/${faculty}/xxx.asp?x_level=2019-2018&xxx=LIKE&xxx=${seatNumer}`, {
            encoding: null,
        });

        // decoding the response to support arabic
        responseBody = iconv.decode(Buffer.from(responseBody), "win1256");

        // parsing the html
        let $ = load(responseBody);

        const stdCode = $('.aspmaker a').attr('href').replace(/[^0-9]/g, "");

        // request to student result page
        let studentResultsPage = await get(`http://xxx/xxx/${faculty}/xx.asp?xxx=${stdCode}`, { encoding: null });

        // decoding the response to support arabic
        studentResultsPage = iconv.decode(Buffer.from(studentResultsPage), "win1256");

        return studentResultsPage;
    }


    async sanatizeData() {
        let body = await this.getStudentResultsBody();

        let $ = load(body);

        let studentDetails: any = $("form > div > table:first-child tr td").map(function (this: any) {
            return $(this).html()
                .trim()
                .split('<br>')
                .map(html => html.replace(/<[^>]*>?/gm, '').trim().split(':'));
        }).get();


        return studentDetails; // getting an issue
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be concerned with the entities in the JSON serialization output. JSON is only intended to be machine readable.

Users don't tend to see the JSON version.

Comment: You are right, and I know that but I will not use this API in a website but in a mobile app made by flutter and flutter also not reading the Arabic text encoded  that coming from the API, So in other meaning, the mobile app displays the text as it shown in the API some encoded text

Comment: @heshamshawky Just to be clear, by API you mean the old win1256-encoded website?

Comment: Yes, buts it's in JSON format now not Html, the issue with text it gets encoded again after I parse it into json

Comment: Thanks yes I know about it and I use it already in some other projects, I have solved the issue it was from `cheerio` it decoding the HTML again after I encoded the first time so I disabled this by putting  decoding to false `let $ = load(body, { decodeEntities: false });`